# In which case should we use Neo4j or other graph database?

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases, non-relational-database

I want to make a blog website and I need a comment system (user can add comments for each article).

take those into consideration:

1. save lots of comments
2. I will save like count
3. I need to rank those comments (the score of a comment is calculated by like count and time, and will change with time)

As there will be lots of insert(add comments) and update(update like count) operations, and I need to range select comments by score of comment, I think relational database is not suitable.

Is Neo4j suitable for this situation?

I want to save each articale and comment as a node of neo4j

Comment: There's really no way to answer this objectively; it's both opinion-based and recommendation-based. What you choose is really up to you and your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As there will be lots of insert(add comments) and update(update like count) operations, and i need to range select comments by score of comment, I think relational database is not suitable.

That is interesting, because it is pretty much one of the things a relational database excels at.
That said it is a rather trivial tasks and any database relational or otherwise should be able to handle this until you get into many millions of comments.

> so, is neo4j suitable for this situation?

As said above, I'm sure Neo4J can handle it. But I don't see anything that plays to the strengths of a graph database. You don't have a complex graph. Your graph simply consists of two types of nodes (`article` and `comment`) with each `comment` referencing exactly one `article`.

I personally consider an RDBMS as the default choice once a flat file isn't sufficient anymore. So I'd pick an RDBMS here as well. But again, the requirements you gave should be easy to handle by any database.

Answer (score 1):

what you describe is not very "graphy".  It becomes more graphy when:

- you want to know which users are similar with respect to the things they comment on
- you have a hierarchical system to "tag" posts and comments
- you have threaded comments with arbitrary depth